# which python module provides utilities for starting multi-threading session (openMP or basethreads)?

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, openmp

I am wondering which python module provides respective utility functions that allow the user to open multithreading sessions (openMP or base threads) for possible parallel processing. Perhaps, there might be handy Python module that does this sort of job, but it is unknown to me. Does anyone know how openMP /base threads that works for parallel processing jobs in Python? Any way to do this? How can I make this happen? Which python module can help me to use multithreading task (either openMP or base threads works for my current need). Any idea?

Comment: What are trying to solve, based on that you could get a possible answer, you question is to general.

Comment: @user1767754 This is part of my current research project. basically, I am trying to parse given sparse data set by using latest parallel machine learning approach - [`hogWild!`](https://medium.com/@krishna_srd/parallel-machine-learning-with-hogwild-f945ad7e48a4). My objective is to implement `hogWild` for logistic regression and analyze given sparse dataset. I did implement respective implementation for those but still struggling to find a solution for multiple threading (such as `openMP` or `base threads`). Any more thoughts?